# Redirect to error page after wrong url is entered, php

Tags: php, video, http-status-code-404

Hey guys :) can you please help me? After I enter the wrong URL on my site it shows me some errors and empty video player.  I am giving you the **example here:** http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=1a660a85e9a2d02e976

If the url is right it shows only the video player and starts to play video correctly without errors, **example here:** http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=6697adb1d9a00acde7a3

Is there any way to change the code in index.php to redirect the user to my random url after user enters the wrong url (the url without any video) ?

External php file [index.php](http://younews.sk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/index.txt)

Comment: That was *a lot* of code - and please provide it here as text in the question, and not as a link to another page. As for your actual question, seems like you just need to write a check if a video exists for that link, and otherwise send a 404 status code (and write a 404 page to deal with it)?

Comment: If there is no video I would like to redirect user to 404 page which I am going to add to random URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, your file() loads a remote URL, if it fails it retuns FALSE, so you can check against it and do whatever you want:

```
$url = "$url_parsovani";
$rows = file($url);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

becomes:

```
$url = "$url_parsovani";
$rows = @file($url);
if ($rows === false) {
  // output something else, redirect the user and so on..
  header("Location: /somewhere_else.html");
  exit();
}
foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your code and I ve change the location to header("http://24tv.cz");

Comment: and I get the error 500, is there anything I ve done wrong? Thanky ou

Comment: Ok fixed, thanxs for your answer.